# Postgresql sqlalchemy default time now() giving same time over and over again

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have field inside table that is time

```
time = db.Column(db.Time, default=datetime.datetime.now().time(), nullable=False)
```

and for some reason it keeps defaulting on same time instead of actual system time

```
"23:53:27.34808"
"20:10:29.613031"
"20:10:29.65371"
"20:10:29.230696"
"20:10:29.613031"
"01:40:41.962449"
"20:10:29.375499"
"09:48:38.981206"
"10:42:38.56931"
"10:42:38.56931"
"10:42:38.56931"
"10:42:38.541895"
"10:42:38.56931"
"10:42:38.56931"
"10:42:38.56931"
"05:01:44.076726"
"10:42:38.56931"
"15:15:18.271026"
"07:29:20.49368"
"15:15:18.271026"
"15:15:18.271026"
```

if you look at times there are 4 or 5 same times and it supposed to take time right now as default option

any ideas to what might be causing it?

Answer (score 7):

`default=datetime.datetime.now().time()` will be evaluated once, at import time, leading to the observed behaviour of all instances being assigned the same value.

The usual solution when providing a Python function as a default is to provide the function object:

```py
Column(..., default=func, ...)
```

but in this case, two function calls are involved (`.now()` and `.time()`), so the solution is to define a function (or a lambda) that performs both:

```py
def default_time():
    # Python 3.12+: datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.UTC).time()
    return datetime.datetime.now().time()

...
    time = db.Column(db.Time, default=default_time, nullable=False)
```

Using this approach, `default_time` will be called each time it's required, and a new value returned for each instance.

See also the SQLAlchemy [docs on using Python functions as defaults](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions).

As user Belayer implies in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862140/postgresql-sqlalchemy-default-time-now-giving-same-time-over-and-over-again/64862796?noredirect=1#comment114687099_64862796), it's common to delegate generating timestamps to the database rather than generating them in Python.  In that case you would set the [server_default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#server-invoked-ddl-explicit-default-expressions) attribute on the column, for example like this:

```py
time = db.Column(db.Time, server_default=sqlalchemy.text('NOW()'))
```

or

```py
time = db.Column(db.Time, server_default=sqlalchemy.func.now())
```

There are various functions on the database side that will generate timestamps, and they are often specific to the particular database engine so you may need to research to find the function that best suits your needs.

Comment: I do not know SQLAlchemy, so I do not know if you can use the following. In straight Postgres now() would be called once for each transaction, if that is not sufficient then you can use [clock_timestamp()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: @Belayer You can do that, by setting  the [server_default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#server-invoked-ddl-explicit-default-expressions) atrribute of the column.

Comment: In Postgres directly you would define the column as "created_at timestamptz not null default clock_timestamp()". How it would be in SQLAlchemy, well again I don't know. I checked you link and di not see anything preventing it, unfortunately nothing specifically permitting it.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this behavior, even though I was writing `server_default='NOW()'` all over the place. Man, is this counterintuitive.

Comment: @winwin Psotgres' `now()` will return the time at the start of the transaction ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)).

Comment: @snakecharmerb, yeah, I know. Do you keep your transactions so long that it would matter? I'm just curious, because in my project I've been trying to not do anything non-database-related inside the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Wanna add to @snakecharmerb's answer. The `sqlalchemy 2.0` way to import the `now` function is:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import now
```

You'd use it like this:

```
class Table(Base):
    # any table
    create_ts: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(server_default=now())
```